# Cannot access any files on Samsung Tab 4 7"

Tags: adb, stock-android, samsung-galaxy-tab-4, droid-explorer

I have a Samsung Galaxy tab 4, 7", rooted but running stock OS (Android 4.4.2. It was rooted using Odin 3.09 and TWRP recovery. I then enabled adb root with the adbd insecure app by Chainfire. It would appear that everything is good to go but when I run Droid Explorer with the tablet plugged in and USB debugging on, it appears to load correctly but then I do not have access to any files or folders. All I see on the left-hand side is a file labeled "/" but I cannot actually open it and it shows "0 objects" at the bottom. I would really appreciate some help here, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Turns out I had failed to install busybox, my mistake!